# Projection of vector $b=[2, 1, 4]$ on the subspace $W={\rm span}([2, 3, 1], [-1, 1, -1])$

Tags: linear-algebra

Problem statement:

*Verify that subspace $W={\rm span}\{[2, 3, 1], [-1, 1, -1]\}$ is orthogonal and the compute the projection of $b=[2, 1, 4]$ on $W$.*

I have solved this as follows:

Let $v_{1}=[2, 3, 1]$ and $v_{2}=[-1, 1, -1]$

**Step #1**: Do vectors are linearly independent?

Yes.

**Step #2**: Find a bassis for $W^{\perp}$:

Nullspace: $\{[\frac{2}{5}r, -\frac{3}{5}r, r]\}$

**Step #3**: Coordinate vector.

Here I solved the following linear system by reducing the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1  & 2 &  2\\ 
3 & 1 & -3 &  1 \ \\ 
1 & -1 & 5 & 4 
\end{bmatrix}\approx\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  & 0 &  \frac{11}{14}\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{10}{7} \ \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{13}{14} 
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Step #4:** Projection of $b$ on $W$:

$b_{w}=\frac{11}{14}[2, 3, 1]+\frac{10}{7}[-1, 1, -1]=[\frac{1}{77},\frac{53}{14}, \frac{-9}{14}]$

Am I correct with this procedure?

Comment: Your general approach is sound (in fact I haven't seen it done this way before and am a bit impressed).  But you made a mistake calculating $W^\bot$.

Comment: Indeed. $[\frac25r,-\frac35r,r]$ is orthogonal to $v_1$, but not to $v_2$.